# java.lang.StackOverflowError on IntelliJ

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I'm new to scala/spark and loading a file(csv) of size 2GB and it works fine on my Virtual Machine with below HEAP_SIZE.

```
HEAP_SIZE="-Xms8g -Xmx8g"
```

But when running the same code and loading the same file on IntelliJ it throws `java.lang.StackOverflowError exception`.
Know I'm not setting the memory options correctly on IntelliJ.
Could someone please help me how and where exactly I need to set this as I have enough memory on my windows machine(32GB)?

By tracing the error, it exactly comes from the below code and obviously at `collect`.

```
val lst: Array[String] = expRDD.map((c: tmpClass) => (c.objType, 0))
  .reduceByKey((x: Int, y: Int) => 0)
  .map({ (t: Tuple2[String, Int]) => t._1 })
  .collect
```

Comment: Did you try the VM Options field of the Run/Debug configuration used to start your app?

Comment: My bad its `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. Yes I tried `VM Options` using `Edit Configuration` by giving the same heapsize.

Comment: Try adding `-Xss4m` in the VM Options. If the issue persists, it's probably caused by some infinite recursion and you will need to share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get help.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Could you please put it as an answer explaining how this works so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increasing the stack size may help. You can specify `-Xss4m` in the **VM Options** field of the corresponding Run/Debug configuration. This will set the stack size to 4M (the default stack size depends on the OS and JVM version and is usually lower than 1M). Note that it will not help if your problem is caused by the infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Scala compile server the JVM options are here:

Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Scala Compiler > Scala Compile Server

(you might have to restart IntelliJ to apply this)

[image: IntelliJ JVM Options]

credits go to @CrazyCoder

Answer (score 0):

[image: This soolved my issue]

Some times it is better to add more heap size like `4096`
and JVM options `-server -Xss256m`